# Is a single layer network technically an ANN? (e.g. input layer straight to output, no hidden layer?)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science

I am working on some content to teach ANN's to gradeschool kids.  I've run across a couple good articles, most of which model a simple XOR problem, using three layers (input, 1 hidden, output).

however, [this](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-simple-neural-network-in-9-lines-of-python-code-cc8f23647ca1) article is a little different in that it simply goes straight from inputs to outputs, with no hidden layer in between.  Most other articles seem to follow the three layer approach for hello world ANN models.

Does this technically qualify as an ANN for teaching purposes, or must we have at least three layers to be an ANN?  (input, 1 hidden, output).  I want to use this simpler model as the first ANN in the content I am producing, but...but only if it technically qualifies as a neural net.

Thanks!

Comment: Better suited to CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @desertnaut thanks, I will post there.  I assumed that because of the availability of ml/nl/dl tags that SO supported these types of questions.

Comment: Short answer: yes, it's a perfectly valid ANN, doesn't have to be deep

Comment: Without a hidden layer you cant solve the xor problem though. Only linear sepparable tasks like AND and OR. The easiest neural network would be the Perceptron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron